# How to play with each other on Minecraft PE with iOS? (Minecraft Version 0.7.5)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to play with my friend on Minecraft PE, but when we connect to the same network, I can't detect his world when he opens his world, and he can't find my world on LAN when I open my world. Does it have to do with the firewall. I went to another friends house and connected to their network and it worked! So what should I do?

Comment: Have you enabled the multiplayer setting in options? My son was able to connect an iPhone with an Android Nexus tablet.